# single-class or multi-class object detection for a specific class object?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, object-detection

One thing that I was wondering for a long time is the **performance of a CNN-based object detector** in **single class** and **multi-class**.

For example, If I want to design a pedestrian detector using the famous Faster R-CNN(VGG-16). The official version could detect pedestrian with 76.7 AP (PASCAL 07 test) if the training data is PASCAL VOC07+12 trainval.

However, I am quite satisfied with the detection results but what if I just revise its framework into a single class pedestrian detector and the training data will only contain pedestrian so both training and testing data will be fewer.

I know the computational power will consume less than the original 20-class one but I am curious about the detection performance.
**has anybody tried to compare single-class and multi-class detector in the same class**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the results vary quite a bit according to model and application.  I've done this with several SVM applications and one CNN.  As expected, the single-class consumed less resource in every case.

However, the results were quite different.  One SVM actually did *better* in single-class training; two were significantly worse, and the other 3-4 were about the same (within expected error range).

The CNN didn't fare so well; it needed some tweaks to the topology.